# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook.sheetIterator()Ljava/util/Iterator;

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

please i need some help on the error. I have a javafx project with the following jar files

- fontawesome-fx-8.1.jar
- sqlite-jdbc-3.8.10.1.jar
- controlsfx-8.40.11.jar
- sqljdbc42.jar
- jfoenix-1.0.0.jar
- POI-3.17.jar
- poi-examples-3.17.jar
- poi-excelant-3.17.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.17.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar
- poi-scratchpad-3.17.jar

And what i need is to import some excel data to it. I have imported the above jar files

But unfortunately when i try to run the project i get the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook.sheetIterator()Ljava/util/Iterator;
at app.controllers.ContentAreaController.nextActionReport(ContentAreaController.java:734)
... 62 more
```

I have tried googling and what suggested is i change the versions of poi lib files but no luck .Can anyone suggest me the solution as i have spent enough time on the issue

Comment: Your application was written against different version of Apache POI then it has on runtime classpath.

Comment: Please ,how can i resolve the issue on javafx project

Comment: Use same jar for compilation and runtime. 
How do you compile/run you app?

Comment: I'm using netbeans ide v8.2 ,so i run directly from IDE ,please

Comment: Download the right jar version. Or, if you are using Maven, go to the `pom` and change it to match the correct version string.

Comment: i added those jar files from the .m2 directory of maven ,so they are from repository

Comment: Use the code in [this Apache POI FAQ entry](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006) to figure out where you older POI jar is coming from

Comment: I get this results after running the check: POI Core came from file:/C:/Users/dnyerere/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Excel%20Report%20Patch/dist/lib/poi-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar!/org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/POIFSFileSystem.class
POI OOXML came from file:/C:/Users/dnyerere/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Excel%20Report%20Patch/dist/lib/poi-ooxml-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar!/org/apache/poi/POIXMLDocument.class
POI Scratchpad came from file:/C:/Users/dnyerere/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Excel%20Report%20Patch/dist/lib/poi-scratchpad-3.17.jar!/org/apache/poi/hslf/usermodel/HSLFSlideShow.class

Comment: So how can i remove those older jar files from classpath because i can not see them

Comment: Thanks @Gagravarr ,i have solved the error. After following on http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006 and delete the classpath jar files that was the older version

Comment: Thanks @Gagravarr see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54668002/1497139 below for a more generic JUnit Test approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Promoting some comments to an answer - you have older Apache POI jars on your classpath. As per [this POI FAQ - mixing POI jars between versions is not supported](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10204)

What you need to do is *just* remove the older POI jars. I say *just*, since you didn't know you had them... Luckily, [if you follow the code in this Apache POI FAQ it'll help you find where the older jars are coming from](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006). Something like this when run on your problematic system should print out the names and locations of the older jars:

```
ClassLoader classloader =
     org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.class.getClassLoader();
URL res = classloader.getResource(
         "org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/POIFSFileSystem.class");
String path = res.getPath();
System.out.println("POI Core came from " + path);

classloader = org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.class.getClassLoader();
res = classloader.getResource("org/apache/poi/POIXMLDocument.class");
path = res.getPath();

System.out.println("POI OOXML came from " + path);

classloader = org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.HSLFSlideShow.class.getClassLoader();
res = classloader.getResource("org/apache/poi/hslf/usermodel/HSLFSlideShow.class");
path = res.getPath();
System.out.println("POI Scratchpad came from " + path);
```

Just identify the older jars you don't want, remove, and you should be set!

Answer (score 2):

Gagravarr's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50472754/1497139 pointed to http://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10006

I modified the code to be used the JUnit Test to fix the same base issue with the following error messages:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getCellTypeEnum()Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellType;
```

Which if first thought was an issue of deprecation. After fixing the deprecation i got:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getCellType()Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellType;
```

which was caused by mixing Apache POI 3.12 and Apache POI 4.0.1 jars in the same project.

To avoid this for the future I created the following Unit test. You might want to adapt the version to your needs or skip the assertion at all while still debugging the issue.

**JUnit Test to check POI versions of used classes.**

```
  /**
   * get the path the given class was loaded from
   * 
   * @param clazz
   * @return the path
   */
  public String getClassLoaderPath(Class<?> clazz) {
    ClassLoader classloader = clazz.getClassLoader();
    String resource = clazz.getName().replaceAll("\\.", "/") + ".class";
    URL res = classloader.getResource(resource);
    String path = res.getPath();
    return path;
  }

  @Test
  public void testPOI() {
    Class<?>[] classes = {
        org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.class,
        org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.class,
        org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.HSLFSlideShow.class,
        org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.class,
        org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType.class};
    for (Class<?> clazz : classes) {
      String path = getClassLoaderPath(clazz);
      if (debug)
        System.out.println(
            String.format("%s came from %s", clazz.getSimpleName(), path));
      assertTrue(path.contains("4.0.1"));
    }
  }
```